# How to find all keys and convert to boolean

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a map with integer values but in a string format

I am trying to filter them based on a key pattern like this:

```
m.filter(f => f.startsWith("user_id_"))
```

A key/value pair looks like:

```
"user_id_a" -> "23453245"
```

So I want to filter the keys by the pattern, and then convert the value to a Long and return that as a List.

Comment: The map is  String -> Boolean?

Comment: Map[String, String] with integer values, sorry corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val m: Map[String,Int]
val filtered = m.filter(_._1.startsWith("user_id_"))
val modified = filtered.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toLong)).toList // If you  want the output to have both string and value
val modified2 = filtered.map(x => x._2.toLong).toList // If you want the output to have only the values
```

Comment: m.filter(f => f._1.startsWith("user_id_")).map(t => t._2.toLong).toList

Answer (score 1):

```
yourMap
 .filter{case (key, value) => key.startsWith("user_id_")}
 .mapValues(_.toLong)
 .toList
```

> I don't understand how do you have a map with boolean but the example is string -> string. I assumed it was a typo